# Handling uploaded files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, heroku, multipartform-data

I am making a spring boot application and I want to be able to upload image files in a form, save them somewhere on the server and the display these images. I managed to get the files using MultipartFile into my controller, however I am not sure how to save the files locally so that I can use them later.

I am guessing I have to somehow save the files in the resources directory so I can access them in my views. I will also be hosting my application on heroku and I am not sure what kind of access to the file system I have there.

Can somebody point me towards a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your MultipartFile you can use FileCopyUtils.copy static method to upload it to a specified directory:

```
FileCopyUtils.copy(multipartFile.getBytes(), new File("src/main/resources"));
```

Comment: I see, but how do I get the path of the resources directory, so I can save them there?

Comment: I'm using this but it won't create files. I use `heroku run bash` to ssh into the instance and `ls` a directory but I don't see any files there. The strange thing is that when I use `Files.walk(dir, 1)` on the same dir I get filenames back! Where are my files? Try this app: https://infinite-woodland-82366.herokuapp.com/.

You'll see the filename in the image src attribute, but the file doesn't load, and it doesn't appear anywhere on the filesystem when I `ls`. How does it list the filename but I can't see it? https://github.com/geluso/SimpleHerokuSpringJavaUploads

Comment: @Pavindu no I'm not sure I ever did!